# Magento 1.9 email creditmemo products

Tags: magento-1.9, email, email-templates

I want to change the layout of the creditmemo productstable inside a creditmemo email.
Inside the following file: `/app/design/frontend/theme/theme/template/email/order/creditmemo/items.phtml`

There I can only find the following code:

```
<?php if($_item->getOrderItem()->getParentItem()) continue; else $i++; ?>
<tbody<?php echo $i%2 ? ' bgcolor="#FFFFFF"' : '' ?>>
<?php echo $this->getItemHtml($_item) ?>
</tbody>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

But where can I find the `<?php echo $this->getItemHtml($_item) ?>` code, to change the layout?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally this code `<?php echo $this->getItemHtml($_item) ?>` referce to this file.

```
app\design\frontend\theme\theme\template\email\order\items\creditmemo\default.phtml
```

You need to change into this according to your requirement.